# Addition in C using Assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86, addition

I am pretty good at C, not so much with assembly, but out of interest i wanted to get some working inside C using gcc. Problem is my program either gives some silly number or crashes.

```
unsigned sadd32(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned c = 0;

    __asm__("movl %%eax, %0" : "=a"(a));
    __asm__("addl %%eax, %0" : "=b"(b));
    __asm__("movl %edx, 0xffffffff");
    __asm__("cmovc %eax, %edx");

    __asm__("movl %0, %%eax" : "=c"(c));


    return c;
}
```

I'm sure i've done something silly, if it's obvious to anyone?? ;)

Comment: Looks to me like you've got the operand order wrong. It should be `source, dest` in AT&T syntax. Plus immediate operands (like 0xffffffff) should have a `$` prefix. There may be other problems as well.

Comment: I think an important point is to use a single `__asm__` block, not several. This makes sure the compiler doesn't insert assembly code between your lines (it might add some before the block, but it's OK).

Comment: You don't need (and should *not* use) inline asm for unsigned saturation.  [How to do saturating addition in C?](//stackoverflow.com/a/166393) has pure C source that compiles to the desired mov/add/cmov with gcc/clang for x86.  **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm**.  This Q&A is only useful as an inline-asm tutorial / example exercise in using GNU C inline asm correctly, not something you'd ever want in real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned sadd32(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned c = 0;
   __asm__ ("movl %2, %%eax\n\t"
                    "addl %1, %%eax\n\t"
                    "movl %%eax, %0\n\t"
                    :"=r"(c)
                    :"r"(a),"r"(b)
                    :"%eax"
             );
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a=3,b=5;
    printf("The sum of %u and %u is %u\n",a,b,sadd32(a,b));
    return 0;
}
```

Referring to : http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

From what I see, your code has some flaws::

```
unsigned sadd32(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned c = 0;

    __asm__("movl %%eax, %0" : "=a"(a));
    __asm__("addl %%eax, %0" : "=b"(b));
    __asm__("movl %edx, 0xffffffff"); /* this here, you are specifying a manual location, may not be accessible or valid */
    __asm__("cmovc %eax, %edx"); /* resulting in its error */

    __asm__("movl %0, %%eax" : "=c"(c));


    return c;
}
```

Also, I believe you did not understand the "=$" concept. From what I see, you are just writing the variable name there, but that is not how it works. From the site, the constraint restraints(as they are known), are as follows:

1. "m" : A memory operand is allowed, with any kind of address that the
   machine supports in general.
2. "o" : A memory operand is allowed, but
   only if the address is offsettable. ie, adding a small offset to the
   address gives a valid address.
3. "V" : A memory operand that is not
   offsettable. In other words, anything that would fit the `m’
   constraint but not the`o’constraint.
4. "i" : An immediate integer
   operand (one with constant value) is allowed. This includes symbolic
   constants whose values will be known only at assembly time.
5. "n" :
   An immediate integer operand with a known numeric value is allowed.
   Many systems cannot support assembly-time constants for operands
   less than a word wide. Constraints for these operands should use ’n’
   rather than ’i’.
6. "g" : Any register, memory or immediate integer
   operand is allowed, except for registers that are not general
   registers.

Refer to the site for more examples and other constraints. Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for some good answers, but for some reason whenever i run these programs a few times they work, and then suddenly I start to get the "this program has stopped working" error!

Comment: @DraconianTimes: I am using Codeblocks 12.11, with MinGW GCC 4.8.0, on Windows 7 64bit. I had no problems running this. Can you give your specs?

Comment: It's very bizarre: a moment ago i was able to compile and run it 4 times in a row, then the 5th time it started to crash again... :O

Comment: Have you tested the other answers? :)

Comment: Have tried other solutions posted here, and they all seem to end in a crash... baffling!! lol

Comment: You'll have to forgive me; it wasn't your code at all! I had some bad memory allocation going in earlier in the code which i removed & now it's working fine! :D

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Code corrected, as Michael commented that this is **saturated add**.

The main points on how to use gcc inline assembly:

1. Put the inline assembly it in one `asm(` ... `)` block.
2. Define input, output and clobbered registers in extended assembly.
3. For optimal register usage, let gcc make decisions on which registers to use, when any general register works equally fine for your code.
4. You don't need to use `mov` to set the values in the beginning of inline assembly block, just define the inputs.
5. Check [GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) carefully, especially the part on [Extended Asm](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#s5).

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned my_sadd(unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    asm(
            "addl %2, %0;"
            "cmovcl %3, %0;"
            /* outputs */
            : "=r"(a)
            /* inputs */
            : "0"(a), "r"(b), "r" (0xffffffff)
        );
    return a;
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned a;
    unsigned b;
    unsigned c;

    a = 123456;
    b = 314159;

    c = my_sadd(a, b);
    printf("%u + %u = %u\n", a, b, c);

    a = 0x80000000;
    b = 0xF0000000;
    c = my_sadd(a, b);

    printf("%u + %u = %u\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, the OP's code is supposed to perform a saturated add (i.e. if the results would wrap around at the 32nd bit it's set to 0xFFFFFFFF). Hence all the extra instructions.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, I understood the code, but didn't knew the term "saturated add" before.

Comment: Even if the compiler accepts this, modifying or clobbering an input-only register is *always* wrong.

Comment: Program seems to crash for me 3 out of every 4 times i run it. So, 1/4 of the time it seems to work. Am using codeblocks to run the program - not sure if that could be why?

Comment: @DraconianTimes I have not used Codeblocks, so unfortunately I can't say. In Linux shell (bash, Debian, x86-64) it seems to work without problems. Have you tried running the program without Codeblocks?

Comment: I can't blame codeblocks for this one lol. I had some bad memory allocation going in earlier in the code which i removed & now it's working fine, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the advice about using a single `__asm__` 'instruction', and AT&T syntax, it might be better to let the compiler load the register with the maximum value. Ideally:

```
/* static __inline__ */ unsigned sadd32 (unsigned a, unsigned b)
{
    __asm__ ("addl %k1, %k0\n\t"
             "cmovcl %k2, %k0\n\t"
             : "+r" (a) : "r" (b), "r" (0xffffffff) : "cc");

    return (a);
}
```

This form also works well on x86-64, where the first and second arguments will be in `%rdi` (using `%edi`) and `%rsi` (using `%esi`) respectively. It would be even better to specify this function with an `inline` qualifier: the compiler might have 'max' already loaded, or may be able to schedule a better way to load it, etc. It also need not return the value in `%rax` or `%eax`.

A lot of tutorials for gcc inline asm are out of date. The best I've found is the [Lockless Inc](http://locklessinc.com/articles/gcc_asm/) tutorial for x86[-64].